# Intersection multiplicity inequality problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

I have a question about an inequality that was stated in my class but never proven. We stated p is simple $I_p(F \cap G+H) \ge \min ( I_p (F \cap G) , I_p(f \cap H))$.

Where we defined  $I_p(F \cap G) = \dim \mathcal O_p (\mathbb{C}^2)/ (F,G) \mathcal O_p(\mathbb{C}^2)$ were we are $(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is the localization at p. 
I think the inequality is correct because we stated it in class, but when I tried to prove it I had difficulties. First when we talk about G+H are we talking about adding the affine varieties defined by them or are we talking about the actual polynomials that define them.

Secondly I see how it can be true if $H$ is a multiple of $F$ because the then $I_p(F \cap G+H) = I_p (F \cap G)$.

Otherwise I do not see why this inequality is true. Can someone actually give me an example where we compute both sides so I can see and hopefully understand why it is true.

Comment: If it happened during your class, I guess the most natural thing to do, at least to me, is asking your professor. I am pretty sure that he or she would be very happy to clarify this since it looks like you are having difficulty in  notation rather than math.

Comment: Sure I will do that!! I was curious for an example.